Slower than expected read speed on Samsung SSD 850 and 870
I have a Samsung SSD 850 (/dev/sda) and a Samsung SSD 870 (/dev/sdb) which are exhibiting slower-than-expected read speeds:
> sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1334 MB in  3.00 seconds = 444.20 MB/sec

> sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1018 MB in  3.00 seconds = 339.03 MB/sec

Meanwhile, I see speeds of 540 MB/s and 530 MB/s advertised on the Samsung website.
As far as I can tell, they are aligned.
For example...
> sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x225d606b

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Are these disks in use at the time? I have two identical SSD's, the one not currently mounted is 40MB/s faster than the mounted (and in use) one

One way to get closer to advertised SSD speeds is to use CrystalDiskMark. Other testing methods might show lower values.

@rint - Why would someone want to buy and install Microshaft windows just to test their disk speeds?

Try running bonnie++ over hdparm. Bonnie is meant for benchmarking, where hdparm is meant for viewing and setting drive parameters.

@JaromandaX It's common sense that test results should be based on the same software. Even on Windows, values measured by different programs can vary significantly. This discrepancy is unavoidable. The same principle applies across different operating systems as well. You don't need to install Windows; just be aware that these differences exist.

Benchmark scores don't really represent much. Actual performance involves many factors. For example, some SSDs slow down when their cache is full.
